# python byte array print() gives wrong values

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, format, byte

Using python 3, I made the following script consisting of a model class containing hundreds of bytearrays and in the same script outside of model class i am printing some of these out to verify they are correct. When i print the values some of values are not what I expected (I put code comments to identify these in the code below).

Here is a shortened version of my script with some of the bytearrays:

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        
        # weird values:
        self.bp_diastole_118 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02\x3b')
        self.bp_diastole_120 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02\x3c')
        self.bp_diastole_122 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02\x3d')
        self.bp_diastole_124 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02\x3e')
        self.bp_diastole_126 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02\x3f')
        self.bp_diastole_128 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02\x40')
        self.bp_diastole_160 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02\x50')

        # correct values:
        self.pupil_r_normal = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x03\xc3')
        self.pupil_r_dilated = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x03\xc4')
        self.pupil_r_constriced = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x03\xc5')
        self.pupil_r_reaction_on = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x03\xc6')
        self.pupil_r_reaction_off = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x03\xc7')
        
m = Model()  

print('--------------weird value------------------')
print('bp_diastole_118 = {}'.format(m.bp_diastole_118))
print('bp_diastole_120 = {}'.format(m.bp_diastole_120))
print('bp_diastole_122 = {}'.format(m.bp_diastole_122))
print('bp_diastole_124 = {}'.format(m.bp_diastole_124))
print('bp_diastole_126 = {}'.format(m.bp_diastole_126))
print('bp_diastole_128 = {}'.format(m.bp_diastole_128))
print('bp_diastole_160 = {}'.format(m.bp_diastole_160))

print('-------------correct value--------------------')
print('pupil_r_normal = {}'.format(m.pupil_r_normal))
print('pupil_r_dilated = {}'.format(m.pupil_r_dilated))
print('pupil_r_constriced = {}'.format(m.pupil_r_constriced))
print('pupil_r_reaction_on = {}'.format(m.pupil_r_reaction_on))
print('pupil_r_reaction_off = {}'.format(m.pupil_r_reaction_off))
```

Here is what is printed to the console:

```
--------------weird value------------------
bp_diastole_118 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02;')
bp_diastole_120 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02<')
bp_diastole_122 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02=')
bp_diastole_124 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02>')
bp_diastole_126 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02?')
bp_diastole_128 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02@')
bp_diastole_160 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02P')
-------------correct value--------------------
pupil_r_normal = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x03\xc3')
pupil_r_dilated = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x03\xc4')
pupil_r_constriced = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x03\xc5')
pupil_r_reaction_on = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x03\xc6')
pupil_r_reaction_off = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x03\xc7')
```

As you can see the good values print exactly what I would expect and are identical to the values I initialized. However if you look at what was printed from the weird values you can see the last 3 characters do not match the values I initialized.

i.e., initialized:

```
self.bp_diastole_118 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02\x3b')
```

is not the same as printed:

```
bp_diastole_118 = bytearray(b'\xff\x01\x02\x01\x01\x00\x02;')
```

Why is this happening and how could I remedy the problem?

Comment: It's a bit of a mindfuck that you've swapped "correct" and "weird" values in the printout vs what your code supposedly does. Are you sure you're using the code you pasted vs the output you're getting?

Comment: Sidenote: `m = ModelSmartStat()` should be `m = Model()`

Comment: oops i forgot to change that part for the shortened. thanks for pointing that out. ill fix it. @Xion

Comment: I swapped them so that they would match what the model class shows thinking it would help people to visually understand. I forgot to swap at the print functions, sorry ill fix that as well @Torxed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are seeing the utf representation of the hex value you set for example utf('0x3b') == ';'

Comment: is that just the result of printing the bytearray object? what i mean is the value of the object is not actually changed, its just printed in a format i dont want? I will try testing this later when i get to my workstation. Thanks for pointing me down a path to start, googling bytearray and reading the docs i couldnt find anything.

Comment: exactly for small example I ran example you can see the correct value is held:


n [21]: x = bytearray(b'\x3b')

In [22]: x
Out[22]: bytearray(b';')

In [23]: x[0]
Out[23]: 59

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found is x3b through x50 they seem to be outputting the last part as special character with x50 being P. If you test using `bytearray(b'\x3b')` it will display the ending for you

Comment: right thats what i saw when i printed them using the code i provided.